# Using contains filter in DynamoDB scan with Java - android

Tags: java, android, amazon-dynamodb

I have aws dynamo db table as follows.
[image]

Now I want to filter it as follows.
[image]

For that I used the following code and i get 0 results in my code.what's wrong with my code.how to fix it?

```
public ScanResult getAllMemos() {
    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(DB_NAME)
            .withFilterExpression("contains(imgName,thumbnail)");
    return util.getAmazonDynamoDBClient(getActivity()).scan(scanRequest);
}
```

Without filter expression I get all results.

Comment: The filter expression syntax is quite weird, I think you need to do something like `"contains(imgName, :search)"` and then additionally call `withExpressionAttributeValues("thumbnail")` on the `ScanRequest`, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html for an example. By the way: you know that `scan` operations should really not be used in any production environment, it defeats the purpose of dynamodb as a key-value store, it actually is quite "expensive" when your db contains a few million records.

Comment: @luk2302 if I use `:search` this gives error and cannot pass `String` to `withExpressionAttributeValues`.it expects a map

Comment: Ah yes, then pass a proper map (as the link) does, have not used the method yet.

Comment: `expressionAttributeValues.put("imgName", new AttributeValue().withS("thumbnail"));` like this?

Comment: Should be `":imgName"` if you use `"contains(imgName, :imgName)"`

Comment: @luk2302 woow.this is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like was discussed in the comments, you need to create an expression attribute value map with the value of the filter and use this.

Try something like this:

```
public ScanResult getAllMemos() {

    Map<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues =
        new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    expressionAttributeValues.put(":val", new AttributeValue().withS("thumbnail"));


    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(DB_NAME)
            .withFilterExpression("contains(imgName,:val)")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues);
    return util.getAmazonDynamoDBClient(getActivity()).scan(scanRequest);
}
```